# Can’t boot into Linux Mint after installing Arch Linux

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint, arch-linux

On my computer, I have Windows 8.1, Linux Mint, and recently Arch Linux, installed in a partition scheme like so

```
/dev/sda1      SYSTEM (Win 8 bootloader, BCD, etc.)
/dev/sda2      Windows 8.1
/dev/sda3      Extended
   /dev/sda6   /home
   /dev/sda8   Linux Mint
   /dev/sda9   Arch Linux
   /dev/sda10  /boot (Grub 2)
```

When I installed Linux Mint, I installed GRUB2 to a `/boot` partition. I then installed Arch, and overwrote the information in `/boot` with `grub-mkconfig`.

It’s now impossible to boot into Mint. I can boot Windows fine, but when I select Mint in the GRUB2 menu, it loads Arch instead. There’s things I would like to use Mint for, but I am unable to now. This is on a BIOS install.

How can I get back into Linux Mint?

Comment: So essentially I should mount the root and not partition, chroot and update-grub from a Linux Mint live USB?